# LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file "glut32.lib". how to fix this error?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-errors

I want to ask a question. I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 6.0 and I was stuck in this #error. `LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file "glut32.lib"` . Actually the command that I used can be run at my computer lab at my college but now I'm using my pc's to run it. I already follow the step to install openGL in my pc's, but it is still stuck. I hope somebody can help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Check your `VC\lib` folder, is there a file called glut32.lib? If not, re-download GLUT and follow the README to put files in the right folder. Here is a link to [GLUT](http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/)

Comment: @user2570637 Then look at your VC6, Project->Settings->Link->Input->Project modules. Add glut32.lib and try again. I'm not sure because I'm using VS2010, but it should be there I think.

Comment: Weher is the folder `VC\lib` located?

Comment: It doesn't work for me either.. even after adding to vc/lib

Answer (score 2):

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\lib

This path is for VS 2013, depending on the Visual Studio Version 11.0/12.0 will be varied

Answer (score 2):

In my case, in visual studio 2019, it was because the **solution platform** was **64**.
So I changed from the dropdown menu left to the `|> Local Windows Debugger` t0 **86** and run it again and it worked
[image: visual studio 2019]
hope this help

Answer (score 1):

In my case:
Right click on project name -> properties -> Configuration Manager(on top right corner) -> Select "x86" at "active solution platform"(platform win32)
===>>> Run

Answer (score -1):

Copy "glut32.lib" to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Lib\winv6.3\um\x86".